# JSON matching NSString with NSDictionary

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, json, uitableview

I'm trying to match my JSON NSString that I got from another UITableView during the preparedtoseg to match up with the nid that both sets of JSON contain the same key.
What I want is that to make this UITableView display only the matched nid content. 
I will post 2 sets of my JSON and my code from the 2nd UITableView. Please help me out guys.

Here is the 1st set of myJSON

```
[
{
node_title: "Fumi",
nid: "9",
Body: "<p>Fumi Restaurant</p> ",
Shop Branch Reference: "8",
Shop Enterprise Reference: "<a href="/drupal/node/7">Fumi</a>",
Shop Service Time: [
"<div class="time-default"> Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday 10:00am - 8:00pm</div> "
],
Shop User Reference: "<a href="/drupal/user/12">suppae</a>"
},
{
node_title: "Shop Number One",
nid: "3",
Body: "<p>This is body for shop number one This is body for shop number one This is body for shop number one This is body for shop number one This is body for shop number one This is body for shop number one This is body for shop number one This is body for shop number one This is body for shop number one This is body for shop number one This is body for shop number one</p> ",
Shop Branch Reference: "2",
Shop Enterprise Reference: "<a href="/drupal/node/1">Fuji</a>",
Shop Service Time: [
"<div class="time-default"> Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday 10:00am - 10:00pm</div> ",
"<div class="time-default"> Saturday, Sunday 9:00am - 10:00pm</div> "
],
Shop User Reference: "<a href="/drupal/user/9">testshop</a>"
}
]
```

Here is the 2nd set of my JSON

```
   [
    {
    node_title: "CTW",
    nid: "8"
    },
    {
    node_title: "Siam Paragon",
    nid: "2"
    }
    ]
```

Now, I managed to implement the match up to solve the problem. 
my issue now is that I need to set the new value for my json after matching so that it can be populated on the UITableview.

Here is my code

```
for(int i = 0; i < [_Json count]; i++) {
        NSString * match =[[_Json valueForKey:@"nid"]objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString * branch =[self.detail valueForKey:@"Shop Branch Reference"];
        if([match isEqualToString:branch]) {
            NSLog(@"Found ");
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: "I need to set the new value for my json after matching so that it can be populated on the UITableview" is not a very good description of your problem -- what is it you want to do???  (First off, remember that you're NOT dealing with JSON, but with NSArrays and NSDictionarys.  And to "mutate" one, to "set" something, it must be "Mutable".  So, close as I can understand your problem, you want to build a new NSMutableArray containing combined values from the two other arrays.)

Comment: @HotLicks sorry for the unwell description, yeah you understood my problem. Basically, according to the both sets of my JSON, my second UITableView will display only one that match the nid with Shop Branch Reference.  Thank you for the very fast reply

Comment: So, build a new NSMutableArray containing the combined values (as new NSMutableDictionarys).  Or use the option on your existing NSJSONSerialization call to return "mutable containers" and modify one of the arrays you have with info from the other.

Answer (score 0):

First, to save you a lot of aggravation: If you put the opening { of a block at the end of the line, Xcode will format it all nicely and not put your code to the extreme right of the screen.

Second, you are allowed to write a method to do all the processing and call it from the block, making your code a lot more readable.

Third, if I had an array of dictionaries, and wanted to find a dictionary with the key/value pair "nid":"8", I'd write

```
for (NSDictionary* dict in array)
    if ([dict [@"nid"] isEqualToString:@"8"])
        NSLog (@"Found the dictionary!!!");
```

Comment: I managed to match up both of my json and string by using for(int i = 0; i < [_Json count]; i++) {
        NSString * match =[[_Json valueForKey:@"nid"]objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString * branch =[self.detail valueForKey:@"Shop Branch Reference"];
        if([match isEqualToString:branch]) {
            NSLog(@"Found ");

but, now I need to set my new json value after matching so that I can populate them on my UITableView.

Comment: Can you help me with my current issue ?