# Getting UIImage to work from JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uiimage

I'm having an issue getting my UIImage to work from the JSon that I received.
Here let's take a look at my JSON

```
[
{
node_title: "Fumi",
node_uid: "11",
users_node_name: "pae",
nid: "7",
Body: "<p>This is Fumi Restaurant</p> ",
Enterprise Address: "99/9",
Enterprise Email: "fumi@gmail.com",
Enterprise Tel: "08111111",
Enterprise Logo: "<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/drupal/sites/default/files/Fumi.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="" />"
},
{
node_title: "Fuji",
node_uid: "8",
users_node_name: "testent",
nid: "1",
Body: "<p>Fuji</p> ",
Enterprise Address: "Somwhere it belong",
Enterprise Email: "ent1@mail.com",
Enterprise Tel: "02-999-9999",
Enterprise Logo: "<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/drupal/sites/default/files/Fuji.png" width="320" height="320" alt="" />"
}
]
```

and Here is my code: I'm able to get all the Json that I received and show them on this ViewController. However, for the [self.detail valueForKey:@"Enterprise Logo"] doesn't seems to work due to the content of the JSON.

BTW, self.detail is the Json object that I passed from the previous UITableViewController by doing preparedtosegue.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.EnterPriseName.text = [self.detail valueForKey:@"node_title"];
    self.EnterPriseTel.text = [self.detail valueForKey:@"users_node_name"];
    self.EnterPriseBody.text = [self.detail valueForKey:@"Body"];
    self.EnterPriseEmail.text = [self.detail valueForKey:@"nid"];

    [self.picLogo setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.detail valueForKey:@"Enterprise Logo"]]];

}
```

I also try this method which works just fine but the content in Enterprise Logo must contain only the URL of that img only. I'm trying to do things as dynamic as much as possible, so I don't expect the static answer. Is there a  way for me to fix this issue ?

```
[self.picLogo setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/drupal/sites/default/files/Fumi.jpg"]];
```

Comment: That's not legal JSON.  It will not parse.

Comment: @HotLicks how do I make it legal then ?

Comment: Have the other end generate legal JSON.

Comment: The above "JSON" sort of looks line an NSLog of a NSArray/NSDictionary tree generated from JSON, except that NSLog logs an array bracketed with `()`, and uses `=` instead of `:`.  I have no idea how you generated the above, and no clue how to interpret it.  If it were valid JSON the key values would be in quotes and the `"` characters in the "Enterprise Logo" string would be properly escaped.

Comment: @HotLicks I got it working now thank Hot Licks  I still couldn't implement the question from yesterday thought T_T 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870595/json-matching-nsstring-with-nsdictionary?noredirect=1#comment34912494_22870595

Comment: And, by the way, NSJSONSerialization had an `error:` parameter -- use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After retrieving the value of `Enterprise Logo` just extract the image URL and request the image using NSURLConnection, NSURLSession, or AFNetworking.

e.g.

```
NSString * __block imageURL = nil;
NSArray * objects = [[self.details valueForKey:@"Enterprise Logo"] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

[objects enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id object, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
{
    NSRange range = [object rangeOfString:@"src="];
    if (range.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        imageURL = [object substringFromIndex:range.location+range.length];
        *stop = YES;
    }
}];
```

Comment: I followed your method but it doesn't work I NSLog the imageURL out and it is still null.

Comment: As @HotLicks mentioned in his comment, the JSON is not legal so it will not parse which is why you are getting a null value.

Comment: I got them working now after following @HotLicks comment 
Thank you very for your help guys! i'm really appreciated

Answer (score 2):

```
Enterprise Logo: "<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/drupal/sites/default/files/Fuji.png" width="320" height="320" alt="" />"
```

The vale for the Enterprise Logo key is html in your json.

```
[self.picLogo setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.detail valueForKey:@"Enterprise Logo"]]];
```

The code you are using is looking for a URL to that image. not the html.

Best practice would be to just have the json have the image url in the format.

```
http://localhost/drupal/sites/default/files/Fuji.png
```

and not the html in it.

Comment: Explain how that even parses.

Answer (score 0):

Extract src value from `img` tag of `Enterprise Logo` that will be the url for image.

To extract the Url, please look into this link: [retrive image url from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278195/retrieve-image-url-from-string)

Let me know if you have any issue :)